# What are those glowing blue shields in Resident Evil 5 for?

Tags: resident-evil-5

They're hidden, and usually out of reach. When you shoot them they shatter but what does it get you? Any sort of bonus or is just for an achievement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get Sheeva's tribal costume collecting all 30 of them

See [here](http://www.gamesradar.com/f/resident-evil-5-bsaa-emblem-guide/a-20090312125435189013) for their location

> Grabbing all 30 gets you that lovely getup, plus something special for Chris and a number of other trinkets

Answer (score 7):

They are the BSAA emblems. There are a total of 30 in the game. If you shoot them you can collect stuff such action figures or buy extra costumes in the "extra" menu voice. And there's also the trophy for getting all of them. :)